# Load SAP's jcoDestination from a .jar file

Tags: eclipse, jar, jco

I have a SAP connection already locally running, with a XXX.jcoDestination on my Project folder (Eclipse Mars). When I export my project generating a .jar I can not get the connection working, although the XXX.jcoDestination was correctly exported (on my opinion!).

I have already tried all three options while exporting, and none of them managed to work.

Have anyone got an idea?

If there is not possible to use this configuration, I would like to pass directly the connection parameters (programmatically or means an external DD.BB.) rather than using the instruction `JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(ABAP_AS)`.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: For me, it remains unclear what you actually want to achieve and what exactly you have already tried.

Comment: I would like to manage pass an absolut path for my XXX.jcoDestination file, so that I can store it in a remote server. At the moment I found out that the SAP example looks for this property file just only in the working directory where the .jar is running, so, to make the whole thing work you have to:

Comment: I would like to manage an absolut path for my XXX.jcoDestination file, so that I can store it in a remote server. At the moment I found out that the SAP example looks for this file just only in the working directory where the .jar is running. I wrote a batch to try pointing absolut (external) paths, wich helped me coming to this conclusion: (1) sapjco3.jar and sapjco3.dll can be alocated externally and in different folders; (2) the XXX.jcoDestination must be together in same folder with my .jar program. And what I would really need to have, is my XXX.jcoDestination in an other folder too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two optyions to read from custom path

- Option 1 : Write the file to any path and set the location to the file in 
  system property with key "jco.destinations.dir"

  System.setProperty("jco.destinations.dir", "path to your properties file");
- Option 2: create custom destination implements DestinationDataProvider
  and override parent method 
  @Override
  public Properties getDestinationProperties(final String sapServerConnectionName) {

Please find complete code sample at [Sample sap jco connection](https://github.com/ihabyousif/sap_jco_client_samples.git) 
There are two projects:

1. sapjcoclient_1 
   the most important line is set environment variable 
       System.setProperty("jco.destinations.dir", "/var/sap/conf/");
   for sap jco client to read from different folder
2. sapjcoclient_2
   implement custom destination to read from different folder.

Comment: @Paul Efford Just let me know and i can create complete sample for you.

Comment: Thanks! it would be very kind of you if you could post a little "working" example...

Comment: Sure, Please read the updated answer and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: @Paul Efford do you have any other questions?

Comment: Thank's! That was very kind of you and helpful!